# Using GDAL 3.6 to convert file geodatabases domains, subtypes and relatioship classes into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, gdal, file-geodatabase, domains, relationship-class

I am using GDAL 3.6.0, with the OpenFileGDB driver, to read a file geodatabase with domains, subtypes and relationship classes and need to convert them to PostGIS.

In the GDAL documentation, it is stated that gdal 3.6.0 supports this, but after running the ogr2ogr command and checking the PostGIS database, it seems not to work. The fields that have domains and subtypes and converted to numeric fields and the descriptions aren't used.

Also, there are no relations between the tables that have relationship classes set up in the original file geodatabase.

Isn't this supposed to work?

I'm using this command in a Debian 11 machine:

```
ogr2ogr -lco SCHEMA=admin PG:"host=xx.xx.xx.xx port=5432 dbname=test user=test password='test'" "fgdb.gdb" -overwrite -skipfailures -progress
```

Comment: I am fairly certain domains, subtypes and relationship classes will not be preserved by the OpenFileGDB driver

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: Hi @ziggy, I'm using debian, but I can use whatever works. The gdal doc I mention is available here gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html. Thanks